# Oracle SQL : Updating a column with count query of another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.
The first one "DISORDERS" with the fields: "ID" number, "Description" varchar2, "MINIMUM_SYMPTOMS" number

with these data:
[image]

The second table is "SYMPTOMS" with the fields: "ID" number, "SYMPTOM" varchar2, "DISORDER_ID" number (FK_DISORDERS_ID)

In my second table i have these data:
[image]

With this query i can find the minimum symptoms (records from the second table) in order for my patient to have the disorder:

```
select DISORDERS.DISORDER as DISORDER, ROUND((COUNT(SYMPTOMS.ID) / 2) ,0) as MINIMUM_SYMPTOMS
from SYMPTOMS SYMPTOMS,
    DISORDERS DISORDERS 
where SYMPTOMS.DISORDER_ID=DISORDERS.ID
group by DISORDERS.DISORDER
```

and i am getting correctly this result:
[image]

I want to update in my first table the field "MINIMUM_SYMPTOMS" and put the MINIMUM_SYMPTOMS value from the last query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't feel like typing that much so I created smaller sample data set.

```
SQL> select * from disorders order by id;

        ID DISO MINIMUM_SYMPTOMS
---------- ---- ----------------
        64 OCRD                0
        65 OCD                 0
       248 GPD                 0

SQL> select * from symptoms order by disorder_id, id;

        ID SYMPTO DISORDER_ID
---------- ------ -----------
         2 test 3          64
         3 test 1          64
         4 test 5          64
         5 test 2          64
         7 test 4          64
         3 test 1          65
         5 test 2          65
         7 test 4          65
         3 test 1         248
         4 test 3         248
         5 test 2         248

11 rows selected.
```

Query - similar to yours - but based only on the `symptoms` table. Why? You don't need `disorders` now; this query will be used a little bit later, in `merge`s `using` clause:

```
SQL> select s.disorder_id,
  2    round((count(s.id) / 2), 0) minsym
  3  from symptoms s
  4  group by s.disorder_id;

DISORDER_ID     MINSYM
----------- ----------
        248          2
         64          3
         65          2

SQL>
```

OK, let's now merge those results with the `disorders` table:

```
SQL> merge into disorders d
  2    using (select s.disorder_id,
  3                  round((count(s.id) / 2), 0) minsym
  4           from symptoms s
  5           group by s.disorder_id
  6          ) x
  7    on (d.id = x.disorder_id)
  8  when matched then update set
  9    d.minimum_symptoms = x.minsym;

3 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from disorders order by id;

        ID DISO MINIMUM_SYMPTOMS
---------- ---- ----------------
        64 OCRD                3
        65 OCD                 2
       248 GPD                 2

SQL>
```

So, yes - that's "how" you'll do that (at least, one option).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` with a correlated subquery:

```
update disorders d
    set minimum_symptoms = (select round(count(*) / 2)
                            from symptoms s
                            where s.disorder_id = d.id
                           );
```

Your example is updating all rows in `disorders`.  If you only wanted to update rows that have a match in `symptoms`:

```
update disorders d
    set minimum_symptoms = (select round(count(*) / 2)
                            from symptoms s
                            where s.disorder_id = d.id
                           )
   where exists (select 1
                 from symptoms s
                 where s.disorder_id = d.id
                );
```